# Upgrading .Net 3.5 to .Net4: MSTEST unit tests fail with puzzling message

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm upgrading a VS solution from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4 (VS2008 - VS2010) prior to moving to VS2013/.Net4.5. However most of my unit tests are now failing.

All those tests whose test class have

```
private TestContext tci;

/// <summary>
///Gets or sets the test context which provides
///information about and functionality for the current test run.
///</summary>
public TestContext TestContext
{
    get
    {
        return tci;
    }
    set
    {
        tci = value;
    }
}
```

defined (and which all pass in the VS2008 environment) now fail in VS2010 and exhibit this error:

```
  Failed    GetValueOrDefault_ValidType_ConvertsResult  Autoscribe.Utility.Test Unable to set TestContext property for the class Autoscribe.Utility.Test.ExtensionMethodsTest. Error: System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext'..
```

I have ensured that in VS2010 the test projects all reference the correct version of the unit test tooling, ie

```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

but the error mystifies me.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? It looks like the nature of TestContext has changed, but it is all boilerplate code anyway so I'm puzzled.

Comment: Check your references, mayhap you have referenced an old version of some MSTest assembly.

Comment: I have ensured that in VS2010 the test projects all reference the correct version of the unit test tooling. The only references other than System dlls are to the VS2010 version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing all references to the VS2010 unit test tooling

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

and replacing them with a reference to the VS2012 tooling

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

which I also happen to have installed. It's bizarre that a VS2012 dll should fix the problem but it does the trick.